# How to enable warning when trait linearization overrides method?

Tags: scala, inheritance, overriding, multiple-inheritance

I have a simple trait inheritance:

```
trait Foo {def foo:Unit}
trait Foo1 extends Foo {override def foo = println("Foo1")}
trait Foo2 extends Foo {override def foo = println("Foo2")}

class FooClass extends Foo1 with Foo2
(new FooClass).foo
//print Foo2 due to linearization
```

I am hoping when `FooClass` extends both traits with overriden method, the compiler can give me a warning for this, saying `Foo1.foo` is overriden and discarded or something, because currently it is just silently overriden. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I doubt you can create a warning, this is exactly one of the use cases of that functionality. What you can do is make `foo` **final** in `Foo1` and `Foo2` so you get an error if you mix in both.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I actually don't want them to be final because it will be overriden in the class in the end, and I will explicitly call either. I just have a lot of mixin traits and some methods got lost in the inheritance and does not have any warninng and caused me debugging trouble

Comment: Would it be too hard to change those mixins? Remember prefer composition over inheritance.

Comment: I guess you can write your semantic linter rule with Scalafix or WartRemover.

Answer (score -1):

Add the `final` modifier to `foo` in `Foo1` and `Foo2`.

And actually it's a good practice in general to make all methods either final or abstract.

Comment: How to mixin both if both are final?

Comment: If you mix in both, then one definition is going to override the other one, which is precisely what you asked how to avoid, isn't it?